# Does there exist a smooth function which is nowhere analytic?

Tags: real-analysis

Smooth means has derivatives of all order, and analytic means can be given as a convergence of power series.

Comment: I suggest keeping this question open, because the answers are different from those for the previous question.

Answer (score 5):

A usual example is 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k\in A} e^{-\sqrt{k}}\cos kx
$$
where $A=\{2^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.